# Change all strings into their real types in array

Tags: php, arrays, casting

I have an array like this :

```
 [▼
  0 => array:47 [▼
    "ProductID" => "37883"
    "ProductCode" => "G-49211"
    "ProductName" => "Preludes"
    "StockStatus" => "2"
    "LastModified" => "2014-02-27T09:50:00-08:00"
    "LastModBy" => "1"
    "ProductPopularity" => "110"
    "AutoDropShip" => "N"
  1 => [
    "ProductID" => "37884"
    "ProductCode" => "G-49212"
    "ProductName" => "Preludes "
    "StockStatus" => "2"
    "LastModified" => "2014-02-27T09:50:00-08:00"
    "LastModBy" => "1"
    "ProductPopularity" => "110"
    "AutoDropShip" => "N"
  ]
]
```

but all values of this array are strings. I want to iterate over this array and cast its values to their original types. if ProductID is integer I want to convert it to integer. Convert dates to real date blabla.

Can this be done ?

Comment: Why do need/want to do this? There is no date type and also which original types anyway?

Comment: how about this values: `"true"`, `"1.44"`, `"null"` ?

Comment: date can be datetime object. Anyway I just want to clear this array. If prices are float or double, I want them to be shown as double or float not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isnt any real function in php that can parse away array elements based on their data types, but still you can do it using **preg_match** pattern matching techniques, by recognizing the characters in each element and then type converting them

idea :-   use a foreach loop and take each element and apply preg_match to check what kind of data that is and then set a data type for it :)

Comment: that sounds like a great idea for now. What if this array has 1000 items, What about performance ? and of course If I wanted this function I should ignore the performance I guess.

Comment: I dont think implementing this will effect the performance, there are rather more performance strains like cryptographic hash generations while login authorizations, Ive once seen how the **php's session id works** and i was struck such huge computations and yet no performance constrains, your problem isnt much compared to those. yet there may be a better way for your problem..